# Syncing html with css first time

Tags: html, css

Im just learning how to do this and im struggling with something that is very simple. I started building a website and I want to sync my CSS with my HTML. On my computer I started a file in my documents called 'development' and inside that folder another folder called 'practise' and inside that folder is my index.html, css folder (with my main.css file) and then my img folder. Here is my HTML code so far. Can anyone out there let me know why the css and html aren't reading one another?

p.s.- Ive tried  
         and

**HTML :**

```
<!DOC TYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Boast | Blah Blah </title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
<header>
    <h1> Ashcroft & Rowe </h1>
    <h5> Blah Blah </h5>
    <nav> 
        <h3>Ad<h3>
        <h3Br<h3>
        <h5>St<h5>
        <h5>De<h5>
        <h5>Com<h5> 
    </nav>
</header>
<body>
    <section>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS link is pointing at "theme.css". If your css file is called main.css and is in a folder try changing it to href="foldername/main.css"

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the full path from where your html file is.

If your html file is practice folder and the css file is in the css folder within the practice folder your link tag should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your folder structure looks like this:

```
development/
    practise/
        index.html
        css/
            main.css
```

so, two problems:

1. Your HTML refers to `theme.css`, not `main.css`
2. the `theme.css` is in a subfolder, but you refer to it without a folder prefix, so the HTML thinks it's *next* to the HTML.

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

And, while you're at it, put the `<header>` element inside the `body` element as @Serlite noted.